# CSV to specific nested JSON

Tags: json, r, excel, csv

I started developing a dashboard using D3Js library to generate plots. Specifically, the [Sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/wizicer/f662a0b04425fc0f7489) library. 
The sample JSON I generated for testing is:

```js
    CC : {
        "2013":{
            "1":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 62, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            },
            "2":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 63, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            },
            "3":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 63, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            }
        },
        "2014":{
            "1":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 61, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            },
            "2":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 63, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            },
            "3":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 63, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            }
        },
        "2015":{
            "1":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 60, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            },
            "2":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 63, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            },
            "3":{
                "PESSOAL":{
                    "Salários Gratificação e Bônus":[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 63, 46, 89, 55],
                    "Horas Extras":[79, 26, 95, 89, 36, 81, 25, 10, 13, 100, 76, 61],
                    "Comissões":[14, 78, 91, 64, 53, 30, 71, 0, 37, 22, 31, 50],
                    "Premiação sob metas":[65, 30, 65, 78, 40, 4, 26, 1, 84, 11, 90, 75],
                    "Ajuda de Custo":[20, 41, 40, 98, 51, 90, 77, 22, 6, 39, 17, 80],
                    "Ajuda de Viagem":[17, 43, 14, 38, 73, 76, 47, 16, 15, 34, 80, 96],
                    "Estágio":[11, 52, 92, 93, 31, 36, 47, 5, 61, 15, 8, 24],
                    "Representantes Comerciais":[39, 79, 79, 91, 17, 33, 26, 51, 70, 98, 42, 63],
                }
            }
        },
    };
```

The problem is, this is a sample code. The data I have is generated through R and it exports as a XLS file, which obviously is not in this format. 
**I need to convert this XLS file below to this JSON format above.**

The data is in this format:

```js
SECTION YEAR MONTH GEXPENSE EEXPENSE VALUE
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Salarios Gratificacao e Bonus 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Horas Extras 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Comissoes Mistas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Premiacao sob metas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Ajuda de Custo 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Comissoes 100% 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Estagio 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PESSOAL Representantes Comerciais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 ENCARGOS FGTS 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 ENCARGOS INSS 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 ENCARGOS Ferias + 1/3 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 ENCARGOS 13 Salario 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 ENCARGOS Indenizacoes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Vale Transporte 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Alimentacao 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Assistencia medica e odont. 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Bolsa de estudo 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Uniformes/EPI 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Seguro de vida 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 BENEFICIOS Cursos e treinamentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_IMOVEL Aluguel de Imovel 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_IMOVEL Iptu 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_IMOVEL Seguro Imobiliario 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_IMOVEL Manutencao Predial 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 IMP_TAX Impostos taxas e alvaras 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 IMP_TAX Contribuicao sindical e patronal 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 IMP_TAX Contribuicao a entidade de classe 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 IMP_TAX Publicacoes Contabeis 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PROMOCAO Anuncios publicacoes e propaganda 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PROMOCAO Eventos feiras e divulgacoes com clientes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PROMOCAO Bonificacoes Concedidas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_VEIC Ipva/Dpvat/Taxa Licenciamento/Despachante 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_VEIC Alugueis de veiculos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_VEIC Combustiveis e lubrificantes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_VEIC Seguro Veicular 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_VEIC Manutencao Veicular Corretiva 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_VEIC Manutencao Veicular Preventiva 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 FRETE Fretes PJ 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 FRETE Fretes PF 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 FRETE Fretes CVLOG 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 FRETE Seguro de carga 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 FRETE Guincho/Munck 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Alugueis de maquinas e equipamentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Energia eletrica 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Agua e esgoto 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Telefone fixo 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Telefone movel 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Internet 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Despesas c/ creditos e cobrancas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Despesas Juridicas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Despesas c/ cartorio 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Correios 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Lanches 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Contratacao de Servicos Gerais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Manutencao maquinas moveis e equiptos. 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Despesas c/ viagens e estadiais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Assinaturas de jornais e revistas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Despesas com Consultoria 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 SERVICO3 Manutencao de Sistemas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PERDA Provisao de creditos nao recebiveis 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PERDA Multas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PERDA Indenizacoes Processuais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 PERDA Perdas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_SERV Material de uso e consumo na oficina 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_SERV Pecas utilizadas em servicos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_SERV Pecas aplicadas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_SERV Despesas com ferramentas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_SERV Outros custos sobre servicos/compras 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_SERV Servicos Internos Aplicados 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 OUTROS Material de limpeza 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 OUTROS Material de escritorio 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 OUTROS Material de informatica 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 OUTROS Despesas com consorcios 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 OUTROS Despesas com acao social e doacoes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 ATIVOS Ativos e Investimentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_FIN Tarifas Bancarias 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_FIN Juros Pagos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_FIN Descontos Concedidos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 DESP_FIN Taxa Flat 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 REC_FIN Descontos Obtidos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 REC_FIN Juros Recebidos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 1 REC_FIN Rendimentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Salarios Gratificacao e Bonus 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Horas Extras 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Comissoes Mistas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Premiacao sob metas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Ajuda de Custo 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Comissoes 100% 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Estagio 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PESSOAL Representantes Comerciais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 ENCARGOS FGTS 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 ENCARGOS INSS 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 ENCARGOS Ferias + 1/3 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 ENCARGOS 13 Salario 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 ENCARGOS Indenizacoes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Vale Transporte 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Alimentacao 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Assistencia medica e odont. 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Bolsa de estudo 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Uniformes/EPI 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Seguro de vida 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 BENEFICIOS Cursos e treinamentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_IMOVEL Aluguel de Imovel 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_IMOVEL Iptu 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_IMOVEL Seguro Imobiliario 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_IMOVEL Manutencao Predial 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 IMP_TAX Impostos taxas e alvaras 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 IMP_TAX Contribuicao sindical e patronal 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 IMP_TAX Contribuicao a entidade de classe 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 IMP_TAX Publicacoes Contabeis 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PROMOCAO Anuncios publicacoes e propaganda 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PROMOCAO Eventos feiras e divulgacoes com clientes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PROMOCAO Bonificacoes Concedidas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_VEIC Ipva/Dpvat/Taxa Licenciamento/Despachante 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_VEIC Alugueis de veiculos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_VEIC Combustiveis e lubrificantes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_VEIC Seguro Veicular 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_VEIC Manutencao Veicular Corretiva 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_VEIC Manutencao Veicular Preventiva 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 FRETE Fretes PJ 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 FRETE Fretes PF 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 FRETE Fretes CVLOG 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 FRETE Seguro de carga 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 FRETE Guincho/Munck 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Alugueis de maquinas e equipamentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Energia eletrica 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Agua e esgoto 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Telefone fixo 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Telefone movel 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Internet 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Despesas c/ creditos e cobrancas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Despesas Juridicas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Despesas c/ cartorio 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Correios 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Lanches 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Contratacao de Servicos Gerais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Manutencao maquinas moveis e equiptos. 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Despesas c/ viagens e estadiais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Assinaturas de jornais e revistas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Despesas com Consultoria 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 SERVICO3 Manutencao de Sistemas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PERDA Provisao de creditos nao recebiveis 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PERDA Multas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PERDA Indenizacoes Processuais 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 PERDA Perdas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_SERV Material de uso e consumo na oficina 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_SERV Pecas utilizadas em servicos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_SERV Pecas aplicadas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_SERV Despesas com ferramentas 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_SERV Outros custos sobre servicos/compras 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_SERV Servicos Internos Aplicados 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 OUTROS Material de limpeza 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 OUTROS Material de escritorio 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 OUTROS Material de informatica 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 OUTROS Despesas com consorcios 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 OUTROS Despesas com acao social e doacoes 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 ATIVOS Ativos e Investimentos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_FIN Tarifas Bancarias 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_FIN Juros Pagos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_FIN Descontos Concedidos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 DESP_FIN Taxa Flat 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 REC_FIN Descontos Obtidos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 REC_FIN Juros Recebidos 0,00
ADM.VENDAS 2015 2 REC_FIN Rendimentos 0,00
```

The dput file is too big for posting here, so I [uploaded](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9N48kfWjrl3M1ZiWFBrNlR0eVE/view?usp=sharing) it to google drive. 
The array in the JSON file is the collection of each month in the specific year for the specific expenses.

What I've tried: online conversion, excel formulas, export direct to JSON through R libraries such as JSONLite, RJson, etc. Didn't get any close.

Any thoughts on what I can try?

Comment: "The data is in this format: See data" - *Please don't do this*. Share a sample of your data using `dput`. Pictures of data are useless.

Comment: I don't know what dput is so I just uploaded the sample as code script. Please, see if it's any better.

Comment: You may read about `dput` usage and other good advice for creating reproducible examples in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't see where you get your numbers from (like `[63, 40, 60, 18, 22, 58, 86, 69, 62, 46, 89, 55]`) - I can't see them in the sample data file.

Comment: It's because it is just a sample. I just typed random numbers. Anyway, the numbers in [] are the numbers in the Values column. For each year/expense. Being the first number in the array the value for that expense in the first month (1) and so on...

Comment: @nrussell, the dput of my data is too big for posting here. I uploaded it to gdrive and the link is live in the question description.

Comment: A sample of your data will suffice; e.g. 50 rows or so.

Comment: Note your JSON snippet isn't valid JSON and your `dput` output will fail because its a data *table* with an internal reference code. Use a data *frame* (and a sample of it as well if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most R JSON packages will output a JSON structure like that if given an R nested list object of the right format.

To figure out the right format, take your sample data and read it in using an R JSON package. Inspect it.

Now use your R skills to regroup your data frame into that list format. Tools such as `dplyr` may help here.

Your data needs to be in a format something like

```
list(CC= list(
  "2013"= list(
    "1" = list("PESSOAL" = list(........),
    ),
   "2014" = list(...
   ... and so on ...
   ) 
)
```

You may find the easiest way is to break the task down into nestable chunks, ie for each of the nested parts of the structure. There's probably no magic R code to do what you want without you having to code it, and nobody will code it for you if you don't give us representative samples of you input and output that are valid.

Comment: I'll accept that as an answer.
I think it was a way to do it, but as I had it in .xls I created a macro and formatted it to coffeescript and then I used js2coffee website to make it a json file. This was the easiest  way I found, altough it's not the ~best~.

Thanks!